# Firestore first()).toPromise() always gives old value even I have re-run with new changes

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have this method on a service:

```
     getUserLink(uid: string): Promise<ConnectionLinkModel> {
            return this.afs.doc<ConnectionLinkModel>
(`userConnectionLinks/${uid}`).valueChanges().pipe(first()).toPromise();
        }
```

This is working fine for the first time. But let's say I have changed the Firestore data manually and re-run this method again (This is very important. I know since this is promise it'll not listen to the changes automatically. But why it doesn't give new value even though I have re-run it again.). But it never gives changed value. i.e. it always gives old value.
How can I handle this use case?

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        const res: ConnectionLinkModel = await 
this.connectionLinkService.getUserLink(this.authService.currentUserUid);
      }
```

**Note:** When Page loads it runs again. But it'll never give new value. Why?

Comment: Please edit the question to give more details about what you mean by "even though I have re-run it again".  What's the implementation on that?  How can we reproduce what you're observing?

Comment: @DougStevenson Done. Please see it.

Comment: When you say "re-run", are you reloading the page, or are you just calling the method again on the same load?

Comment: @DougStevenson Actually this is on a Modal page. i.e. There is a button on a parent page to load the Modal page. So even though I have changed the Firestore LinkId (i.e. this is what above Promise returns) it always gives old Id. Any clue about how to handle this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [enabled persistence](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline) then the first data you'll get will always be from the local cache.

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline):

> To check whether you're receiving data from the server or the cache, use the fromCache property on the SnapshotMetadata in your snapshot event. If fromCache is true, the data came from the cache and might be stale or incomplete. If fromCache is false, the data is complete and current with the latest updates on the server.

```
 getUserLink(uid: string): Promise<ConnectionLinkModel> {

                return this.afs.doc<ConnectionLinkModel>(`userConnectionLinks/${uid}`)
                                 .valueChanges()
                                 .pipe(debounceTime(1000)).pipe(first()).toPromise();
            }
```

Comment: Yes, I have this `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),` . So how can I handle this use case with `Promise`?

Comment: This is not necessarily the case. There's nothing in the documentation that suggests enabling persistence will **always** cause a query to consult the local cache first before going to the service.  `fromCache` exists so you can tell **if** a document came from cache.  If the service response is very slow (for example, with a flakey connection), then you will get cached results.  But the cache isn't the default, unless you specifically told `get()` to use the cache only.

Comment: @Sampath you could debounce the observer for a few milliseconds, for example.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, that's good to know. *Always* should perhaps be *often* in this context.

Comment: If your connection is good, "often" is not even really the case.  The SDK keeps an internal timeout on the request to the server, after which cached results are returned.  How often this timeout is exceeded is going to be a function of how good the connection actually is.

Comment: @DougStevenson is this specific for web clients, or is this how it works on iOS and Android clients as well?

Comment: @augustzf How can I `debounce` since I have a `Promise` no?

Comment: @Sampath This could work: `valueChanges().pipe(debounceTime(500)).pipe(first())`

Comment: All client platforms should work the same, except where indicated by the documentation.  If you observe something different, you can open an issue on GitHub for the outlying SDK platform.

Comment: @Sampath If you only want non-cached values then you could use an RxJS filter instead of debounce: `valueChanges().pipe(filter(snapshot => !snapshot.payload.metadata.fromCache)).pipe(first())` in your `getUserLink` function.

Comment: @augustzf If I have removed `.enablePersistence()` then it works nicely. And this too works with `.enablePersistence()`  `debounceTime(1000)`. I had this problem for a very long time. This is a great help. Thanks a lot.